# How to get Google's Search Suggestions

Tags: google-search

Is there any way to get the Search Suggestions from Google?

For example, if I have an input Jay Z, is there a way I can get the suggestions:

- Jay Z and Beyonce
- Jay Z Net worth
- Jay Z Rachel Roy

If you're confused about my question, think: I have 1000 search terms, I want to know the search suggestions for all these terms.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: If you are willing to learn something, use WireShark to inspect the HTTP traffic and see how the results comeback. Anyways, this question belongs on [su] as it is not exactly about programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are apps already that scrape these, an example is [Keyword Shitter](http://keywordshitter.com/). Depending on why you want these, you could look at the Keyword Planner in Google Adwords for similar search suggestions instead of the engine.